# BootStrap Navbar Collapse issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I commented out the remainder of the code to see if it was any of the outside elements that was causing the issue, they're not. jQuery is linked and so is BootStrap. The button shows up, but the collapse feature is not working. Maybe it's just my eyes and I spelled something wrong, but what's wrong in this code?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
 <div class="container">
<div class="navbar-brand">
  <a href="#about">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lamp"></span>Tommy Mertell
  </a>
</div>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lamp" style="color:white;"></span>
  </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#port">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can we see a fiddle/pen of the page? Seeing the JavaScript and how it's interacting with the HTML is critical.

Comment: I commented everything out, the only thing that is not commented it out is the code you see right here and it's not working still.

Comment: Seeing the JS is still important: it could be it that is causing the problem.

Comment: You `data-target` is set to the `.navbar-collapse` class. Add an `ID` like `<div id="myNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">` and change your data-target to `myNav`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Tugzrida - There is no Js, well beside the bootstrap jQuery source code.

Comment: Chris - Yes, thank you, I have already tried this and it did not work. I actually changed it to what you see here as a result of looking through others problems first.

Comment: Tommy, I'm only other advice is to check the browser console for any possible errors and debug from there.

Comment: Are you positive you're loading the Bootstrap JavaScript below jQuery?

Comment: Tania and Tugzrida, I will add a picture.

Comment: Please see my answer and view the [working pen](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/RrPeRb) I have created for you. Also, if you can show us an image, why can't you link to your pen?

Comment: I honestly don't know how, I'm used to working with desktop IDE's, using Code Pen is somewhat new to me Tania.

Comment: @Tommy Mertell Just post the URL for the pen and we can take a look at it.

Comment: http://codepen.io/sinithwar/pen/QybQPm?editors=100

Comment: @Tommy Mertell Please see my updated answer for the actual solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up console and make sure you don't have any errors on the page. I copied your code and put it on a page with Bootstrap and jQuery and it was working for me.  Although you should change the structure a bit because there were some horizontal scrollbars.  I would put your branding and your navbar-toggle button inside of a div with the class navbar-header to start.

Comment: For some odd reason that worked adding "the heading part" can you tell me why?

Comment: @Tommy Mertell Explanation to your problem in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a fiddle with your updated pen](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/OMVBmX).

You did not end your comment.

You started a comment...

```
<!--
```

But you did not add the ending comment line.

```
-->
```

Because of this, the jQuery and Bootstrap are not loading at the end of the page.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this once I searched through the code but Frank's answer is what solved it for me. Even when I corrected the HTML comment, it didn't work properly until I added the containing class of navbar-header. Thank you for pointing it out though. :)

Comment: You will notice in the pen I posted here that it works, and does not have the `navbar-header` class.

Comment: I know, but for some odd reason, mine still didn't work properly even after I corrected the HTML comment. Maybe it's buggy?

Comment: Most likely the pen did not update until you made some more changes. Sometimes it takes a moment or two, or you might need to change non-commented code for the pen to update. In any case, I'm glad a solution was found to your problem - however, it is useful to note that the solution was due to your jQuery and Bootstrap being loaded properly, not the addition of a class to your navigation.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. However, my problem was not the loading of jQuery and BootStrap. It was providing me with this problem even before I made the HTML comment error. This may have caused a refresh of the libraries, which may also be what fixed it though. Pitty I can't mark more than one answer as correct. :(

Comment: I can't tell you what your problem was before you posted it, but that was the issue at the time of posting. You *were* including them properly, however they were not loading properly, because of the comment. If you click "Change View -> Debug Mode", it will take you to a full page screen of your pen, in which you can see the HTML that is output. [Here is your pen before any changes were made](http://s.codepen.io/taniarascia/debug/OMVBmX) in debug mode - if you view the source, you can see the jQuery and Bootstrap are not loading, because they're commented out. This will help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing the script and link tags to bootstrap and jquery and put these (following the same order).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Maybe is something related to versions, or the order you're loading scripts/css.

Hope that helps!